# Why does my device keep crashing into boot loop?

Tags: boot-loop

I have tried several 'solutions' for resolving boot loop issues.

My MT6582 keeps crashing. Every 2-5 days, I have to re-flash the stock ROM and start all over again. I've tried different scatter files and using SP Flash Tool to flash them to the phone but the tool either gives me an error or the phone boots back into boot loop.

I've tried:

1. MTK droid Tools, Mobile Uncle, MagicBox, TWRP, CWM, PHILZ...following all of the tutorials and guides to the letter but, so far, nothing has worked...
2. Sideload.
3. Creating a custom ROM using kitchen.

If there's a 'possible fix' out there on the web, I think I've tried it.

Can someone help me with this problem? I'm sick of flashing my phone and reloading all the apps, setting preferences and then having it crash! At the very least, I should be able to create a scatter file that has my apps, userdata and preferences that I can flash when needed.  (Teach me how to do that!)

The phone is a Blu Studio 5.0 C HD (Mediatek 6582) with KitKat 4.4.2

Comment: Mediatek devices have a track record of not liking root. It could also be a kernel bug. It can't be much else. It really can't. +1 For providing all the info we would normally ask for, too.

Comment: Have the same phone with similar issue. The problem comes from the eMMC. There is no fix unless replacing the chip.Mine won't power on anymore